# How to pass an additional variable into React.forwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to update my application to Material UI V4 and I need to use React.forwardRef when generating the component for the button LinkItem but I have a dynamically generated List and need to pass the 'to' string as a variable/prop.

The ListItem is generated like this:

```
<ListItem 
  key={childData.display} 
  button 
  component={(routerProps) => renderLink(childData.link, routerProps)}
>
  <ListItemText primary={childData.display} />
</ListItem>
```

With renderLink passed down as a prop from the parent component:

```
renderLink = (link, routerProps) => <Link to={link} {...routerProps} />;
```

I have tried:

```
const renderLink = link = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Link to={link} {...props} ref={ref} />)
```

and:

```
renderLink = (link, routerProps) => {
  const props = {
    link: link,
    ...routerProps
  };
  return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Link to={props.link} {...props} ref={ref} />)
}
```

but neither of these have worked and I don't know how I can make this work.

Relevant documentation: https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#caveat-with-refs

Comment: Not sure if its a typo or not:


```const renderLink = link = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Link to={link} {...props} ref={ref} />)
```

should work as: 

```const renderLink = link => React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Link to={link} {...props} ref={ref} />)
```

Comment: Just tried this and it hasn't worked either. At this point, I'm quite happy restructuring the thing I'd just like it to work.

Comment: And you're calling it like `component={renderLink('path/to/route/to')}`?

Comment: I asked another (rephrased) question about this problem and now understand how to make it work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383088/can-this-forwardref-be-moved-into-a-function-for-reusability/56383832#56383832

Comment: Nice! Glad you got it sorted :)