# Can this forwardRef be moved into a function for reusability?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am in the process of moving my application to Material UI V4 and I am struggling to move my react router Link components into forwardRef wrapped components when the 'to' prop is set programmatically.

The below code works but requires duplicating the call to forwardRef and building the props object and I would prefer to do that work in a function that is called once with arguments but I cannot work out how to do it.

```
const ViewLink = (props, ref) => {
    console.log(props);
    switch (props.type) {
        case 'entities':
            return <Link to={`/entities/${props.id}`} {...props} innerRef={ref} />;
        case 'templates':
            return <Link to={`/templates/${props.id}`} {...props} innerRef={ref} />;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

<Button 
    className={classes.buttonFont}
    component={React.forwardRef((props, ref) => ViewLink(
        { 
            id: childData.id, 
            type: type, 
            ...props
        }, 
            ref
    ))}
>
    {childData[column]}
</Button>
```

Is there a way to create a single function that handles both the switch statement and the forwardRef? Ideally, something called as per below:

```
<Button 
    className={classes.buttonFont}
    component={(props) => ViewLink(id, type, props)}
>
    {childData[column]}
</Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following should work fine. `ViewLink` can be defined in a separate file and imported if you want to reuse it. Any properties that you need to pass to `ViewLink` can be passed by specifying them on the Button element. That allows the `component` prop to point at a reusable type rather than an inline function.

```
const ViewLink = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    console.log(props);
    switch (props.type) {
        case 'entities':
            return <Link to={`/entities/${props.id}`} {...props} innerRef={ref} />;
        case 'templates':
            return <Link to={`/templates/${props.id}`} {...props} innerRef={ref} />;
        default:
            return null;
    }
});
```

```
<Button 
    className={classes.buttonFont}
    id={childData.id}
    component={ViewLink}
>
    {childData[column]}
</Button>
```

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much, I wish I had known that two days ago.